# Can't create a new Windows Azure Project - "Requested registry access is not allowed "

Tags: visual-studio-2008, azure, registry

When I attempt to create a new Cloud Service project, after it prompts me for 'Roles', I get the following error message and VS just stops:

"Requested registry access is not allowed "

I am running Visual Studio as an administrator, so what gives?

I found a couple of sites that mention using "subinacl" to correct the permissions, but I don't know what keys are failing and there aren't any events describing where the failure was in the event logs.

I really want to start an Azure project, can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same problem. Win7 Home Premium 4GB RAM. Visual Studio 2010 Express (VB, C#, C++, Web). I didn't need to Run as Admin because my UCL is off. When I got the "Requested Registry Access is not allowed" error when trying to create a new project (in VB, C3 or C++), I shut down VS2010 and Googled for answers. I couldn't believe that Microsoft didn't have a viable solution. And some solutions called for a blank change of the entire registry! OMG ... (needless to say I didn't go down that path).

Looking at my registry I see that several HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VCSExpress...... entries. When checking the permissions for one of them (VCExpress.Launcher.vcproj.10.0) I found that the VS2010 install program has created a new user called 'msiserve' and appears to of made this new user the owner, but neither the Administrators Group, or the Administrator has any permissions.

I tried changing the owner to me (I'm an Administrator) but Windows wouldn't let me. I also couldn't add a new user (Everyone) either.

So I'm stuck for the time being.

I did read somewhere that the latest KB updates automatically fixes the problem. So I'll go and try the **subinacl** tool ...

Ok, that worked. Here's what I put inside a CMD batch file ...

```
cd /d "C:\Program Files\Windows Resource Kits\Tools\"

subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBExpress.Launcher.vbproj.10.0 /setowner=Mark-CQ61\Mark
subinacl /subkeyreg HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VBExpress.Launcher.vbproj.10.0 /grant=everyone=f  /grant=administrators=f /grant=system=f

pause
```

After running this I was able to access the registry key and I was able to create a new VB project (don't forget to change my domain/owner string "Mark-CQ61\Mark" for your own!!).

Now to do the same for C++ and C# ...

Comment: I had the same problem on Windows Vista 64 bit, and this solved my problem